# Deploy and run a Go API server on Ubuntu/Centos

Tags: rest, api, go, digital-ocean, slack-api

I just finished my first backend with Go using Iris framework but now I need to put it on production so I can use it in the Slack app I built.

In order to test the code locally I only run my file with `go run main.go` and `ngrok` to test with the Slack API, it's working and it's finished.

I have a droplet with Ubuntu 16.04.3 and other one with Centos 7... I was searching for something like `pm2` for go, running the server and using nginx to point that port but I read that with Go it's different and I have to use something like this https://fabianlee.org/2017/05/21/golang-running-a-go-binary-as-a-systemd-service-on-ubuntu-16-04/

But that's a very long configuration for a simple server and my questions are:

- Is this the usual way to config the APIs with Go?
- Apart of DigitalOcean, do you recommend to use a different service to run my API?

This is really my first time with Go and I just want to learn more, I am a backend developer with Laravel and NodeJS.

Comment: try http://supervisord.org. We used it with Go and works well. The better way is to use docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most people use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) for this purpose, including me.

To make it very easy for you, just take a look at [my Golang project, isaac-racing-server](https://github.com/Zamiell/isaac-racing-server#install-as-a-service-optional) and use it as a template for yours by replacing `isaac-racing-server` with the name of your app. (The Supervisor files are in [a subdirectory](https://github.com/Zamiell/isaac-racing-server/tree/master/install/supervisord).)

Comment: Thank you @James, I'm going to take a look at your project, very useful!

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as accepted because you were the first but the answer of @Muhammad it's also perfect for what I am doing :) Thank you guys!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `pm2` if you want. When you build a go project it creates a binary executable, lets say `backend-server`, which you can run from terminal and will start the app like this:

```
$ ./backend-server
```

If it's not executable or has permission denied issue, add the executable permission to it.

```
$ chmod +x backend-server
```

You binary should be ready to run. I like to do it with a json config file (`process.json`) so that I can pass extra env variables as well and don't have to type a lot in terminal.
My `process.json` looks something like this:

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "backend-app",
    "script"      : "./backend-server",
    "env": {
      "DB_USER": "db_user",
      "PORT": 8080
    }
  }]
}
```

Finally you can start the app using pm2 like this:

```
$ pm2 start process.json
```

More details about json config can be found in [official doc](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)

Comment: That's also clever and I am going to try it out, thanks1